# SFDX Scratch Org Creation - queueRoutingConfigs - Not Available for Deployment to your organisation

Tags: salesforcedx, omnichannel, scratch-org-definition-file

I'm attempting to create scratch orgs via GitLab pipeline which includes LiveAgent, Omni-channel and skills.

Looking at the [Metadata Coverage report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/50/QueueRoutingConfig/details) I can see that queueRoutingConfig is supported. And that the developer documentation for this requires Omni-Channel to be [enabled](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_queueroutingconfig.htm)

> force-app/main/default/queueRoutingConfigs

My hunch is that sfdx isn't enabling Omni-Channel properly. Does anyone know why?

Project Scratch Def file

```
    {
    "orgName": "****",
    "edition": "Enterprise",
    "features": ["PersonAccounts","Communities", "Entitlements", "MultiCurrency", "LiveAgent", "SocialCustomerService", "ServiceCloud", "ServiceUser", "Knowledge", "SalesUser", "ForceComPlatform", "API"],
    "settings": {
        "orgPreferenceSettings": {
            "s1DesktopEnabled": true,
            "s1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
        },
        "knowledgeSettings":{
            "enableKnowledge": true
        },
        "nameSettings" :{
            "enableNameSuffix":false
        },
        "liveAgentSettings" : {
            "enableLiveAgent":true
        },
        "emailAdministrationSettings": {
            "enableEnhancedEmailEnabled": true
        },
        "omniChannelSettings": {
            "enableOmniChannel": true
        },
        "caseSettings": {
            "systemUserEmail": "support@acme.com"
        },
        "lightningExperienceSettings": {
            "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
        },
        "communitiesSettings": {
            "enableNetworksEnabled": true
          },
        "quoteSettings" : {
            "enableQuote" : true
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Metadata Coverage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/50/QueueRoutingConfig/scratch-def/developer) you provided also has a tab for sample scratch definition

```json
{
  "orgName": "Sample Org",
  "edition": "developer",
  "settings": {
    "omniChannelSettings": {
      "enableOmniSkillsRouting": true,
      "enableOmniChannel": true
    }
  }
}
```

You'll notice you're missing `enableOmniSkillsRouting` within [OmniChannelSettings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_omnichannelsettings.htm) which I presume is why you're running into that error.

> Indicates whether **skills-based routing is enabled in your org**. The
> default value is false.